# Comparing between layers name and merging layers having same name using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I'm trying to write python script in QGIS to merge layers having the same name.

To do that I specify the name of layer in the script, so all layers having this name, will be merged.  However, since  I have a lot of names this is not practical. I tried to convert the names type from unicode to list to be able to iterate in the list of names.

In this script, I specify layer name. I want to iterate over all names and compare them to finally merge layers having same name.

```
import qgis.core
import processing
def __init__(self, iface):
    self.iface = iface
lyr_list=[]
count=1
layers=iface.mapCanvas().layers()
for i in layers:
    if i.name() == 'layer_name':
        lyr_list.append(i)

processing.runandload("qgis:mergevectorlayers", lyr_list, "memory:merged")
```

Comment: please share your script, so we can answer your question more precisely!

Comment: Have you tried to create a dictionary where the key is the layername, and the value is a list of all the layers that have that name?  Once you have a dictionary populated you should be able to runandload once for each key in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks@Kirk Kuykendall for your response. How can I create this dictionary in python?

Comment: @nermiiine In my answer you have an example of this parameters dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Following code has an example of parameters dictionary and, I modified some little thing in your code because you are tagged this question with qgis-3 and 'runandload' doesn't exist as processing method in pyqgis3. I also modified 'layer_name' for working with my own layers.

```
import qgis.core
import processing
def __init__(self, iface):
    self.iface = iface
lyr_list=[]
count=1
layers=iface.mapCanvas().layers()
for i in layers:
    if i.name() == 'polygon1':
        lyr_list.append(i)

processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:mergevectorlayers", 
                             {'LAYERS': lyr_list, 
                              'OUTPUT': "memory:merged"})
```

So, I loaded same layer twice in Map Canvas of QGIS 3 and, I ran above script in Python Console.

Result (layer **Merged**) can be observed in following image with attributes table. It worked.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @xunilk for your answer, just I don't want to specify the layer name in the code. So I tried to create a combobox which display layers name. It work fine. If you have any other suggestions will be very helpful